# Visual Relations using Winium automating a WPF app

Tags: wpf, winium

Using other automation tools for Windows Apps, such as LeanFT, there is a way to specify a visual relation. For example, if I identified a label, I could then say look for the text box to the right of it.

Is there a way to do this in Winium?

Here is a sample of what the code looks like in LeanFT

```
var projectButton = baseOR.PlatformWindow.ProjectList.BrowseProjects.Describe<IButton>(new ButtonDescription
                {
                    FullType = "button",
                    Text = node,
                    Index = 0
                });

                return baseOR.PlatformWindow.ProjectList.BrowseProjects.Describe<IButton>(new ButtonDescription
                {
                    FullType = "button",
                    Vri =
                    {
                        new VisualRelation
                        {
                            TestObject = projectButton,
                            HorizontalRelation = HorizontalVisualRelation.LeftAndInline,
                        }
                    }
                });
```

As you can see, we are essentially identifying one element, and then using that as the TestObject in the VisualRelation to identify something else.